# How to avoid special characters in android SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, search, special-characters

How I should write my sql query in android that special characters work correct. For example when I filter String with like which has % symbol, it doesn't work correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `LIKE`, you choose in the query what to escape them with;

```
SELECT * FROM Olle WHERE name LIKE 'Many ^% have fallen' ESCAPE '^';
```

...will only match the actual character `%` since it's been escaped with the `^` that is give in the ESCAPE clause.

SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/85312/2).

Comment: Is there any other characters that I need to escape in like query?

Comment: @Vahan Only `%` (any string), `_` (any character) and the escape character itself.

Comment: I write in java String.replace("%", "^%"); it doesn't replace, I think because % is special character in java, can you help me please?

Comment: @Vahan The correct way to use it is `String stringWithPercentReplaced = originalString.replace("%", "%^");` It doesn't replace in the original `String`, it returns a new `String`.

Comment: @ Joachim Isaksson,Thank you, I also have to replace underline? and how to escape the escape character itself, witj replace("^","^^") ?

Comment: @Vahan Yes, `_` should be replaced with `^_` and `^` should be replaced with `^^`.

Comment: @ Joachim Isaksson but ^ without replacing works correct in search, thank you very much, you helped me a lot :))